# How do I find and count identical values in an array, then insert a node with: ‘count: (int)’ via PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have a dynamic array of latitudes and longitudes, but I need to *insert the count of identical values* while *eliminating the duplicates* via PHP. So this...

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
            [lat] => 40.7587979
            [lon] => -73.9623427
        )
    [1] => Array (
            [lat] => 39.8587028
            [lon] => -84.277025
        )
    [2] => Array (
            [lat] => 37.7647993
            [lon] => -122.4629897
        )
    [3] => Array (
            [lat] => 37.7647993
            [lon] => -122.4629897
        )
    [4] => Array (
            [lat] => 33.5125302
            [lon] => -117.6860507
        )
    [5] => Array (
            [lat] => 39.8587028
            [lon] => -84.277025
        )
)
```

...becomes this...

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
            [lat] => 40.7587979
            [lon] => -73.9623427
            [count] => 1
        )
    [1] => Array (
            [lat] => 39.8587028
            [lon] => -84.277025
            [count] => 2
        )
    [2] => Array (
            [lat] => 37.7647993
            [lon] => -122.4629897
            [count] => 2
        )
    [3] => Array (
            [lat] => 33.5125302
            [lon] => -117.6860507
            [count] => 1
        )
)
```

I understand using array_count_values(), but that doesn't insert the new count values within each node. The use case would be a heatmap where the map is weighted based on the number of identical coordinates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways to approach this involving loops and conditionals, but `array_count_values()` works very well for large sets. Here's a loop that bundles `array_count_values()` with `array_map()` to:

1. `array_map()` converts the `lat,lng` array pair of the *original* array into an array of string `lat|lng`
2. `array_count_values()` counts the unique values of those `lat|lng` strings and returns them as array keys pointing to the count as values
3. `foreach` loop iterates that array of `lat|lng` keyed counts and splits them back out into the output sub-arrays.

---

```
// To hold the new array
$out = [];

// Outer loop over the result from array_count_values()
foreach (array_count_values(array_map(function($l) {
    // Map function combines lat|lng
    return implode("|", $l);
  // The rest of the loop syntax...
  }, $original_array)) as $pair => $count) {

  // Split the counted array key back to individual lat,lng
  list($lat, $lng) = explode("|", $pair);

  // Put it all onto the output array
  $out[] = [
    'lat' => $lat,
    'lng' => $lng,
    'count' => $count
  ];
}

print_r($out);
```

Prints:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [lat] => 40.7587979
            [lng] => -73.9623427
            [count] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [lat] => 39.8587028
            [lng] => -84.277025
            [count] => 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [lat] => 37.7647993
            [lng] => -122.4629897
            [count] => 2
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [lat] => 33.5125302
            [lng] => -117.6860507
            [count] => 1
        )

)
```

Note: One difference from your example output is that you retained the *original* outer array keys after discarding duplicates `0,1,2,4`. This output is a fresh array numbering all outer keys sequentially `0,1,2,3`. If you actually need to keep the original array keys, more will need to be done.

[Working demonstration](https://3v4l.org/RT6m6)

Comment: Thank you! Question: Is `$l` the variable of the original array? So `$l = array(`etc...?

Otherwise I get errors: `Warning:  Undefined variable $a ... on line 146
Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: array_map(): Argument #2 ($array) must be of type array`

Comment: Good catch on the outer array keys. That was a typo. I edited the original.

Comment: @schmelding I was working with `$a` as the original array. I edited above to make that more clear, apologies for forgetting that initially. `$l` is just the array iteration variable passed into the map function.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much!

Comment: You should probably put this into a function just in case you want to use it again, simple to do. Very great answer though bud :) Example Function: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d2b3530f3fe21e19f1881079f2c6cffc0904b021